# Function as an argument of a constructor of std::function wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am writing Monitor class for synchronization problem and I would like to implement an 'Entry' class that will wrap a std::function.

I implemented it a bit, used function traits, but right now I am only able to construct Entry objects using prepared std::function object. Attempts to write a constructor that has an plain function as a parameter failed with compiler messages about template argument deduction/substitution and <anonymous> parameter.

The program is working but I am just curious how to implement given constructor, this is my code:

```
template <class F>
struct FunctionType;
template <class R, class Object, class... Args>
struct FunctionType<R (Object::*)(Args...)> {
  typedef R return_type;
};
template <class R, class Object, class... Args>
struct FunctionType<R (Object::*)(Args...) const> {
  typedef R return_type;
};


template <class F> class Entry {
    std::function<F> internalFunction;

    ...

public:
    template <F> Entry(const F& function){
        // It doesn't work.
    }

    template <F> Entry(const std::function<F> function) :
        internalFunction(function) {

    }

    template<F, class... Arguments>
    typename FunctionType<F>::return_type operator()(Arguments... arguments){
        return internalFunction(arguments...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

```
template<F>
```

doesn't make any sense at all. You get the type of `F` from the template parameter on the class, use that and remove this altogether.

Next, it's probably easier for you to use a trailing return type on your `operator()` function:

```
template<class... Arguments>
auto operator()(Arguments... arguments) -> decltype(internalFunction(arguments...))
{
  return internalFunction(arguments...);
}
```

(If you have C++14 you can just use `auto`).

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb6d6d17ea00aa20)

---

Here's your fixed class

```
template <class F> class Entry {
    std::function<F> internalFunction;

public:
    Entry(const F& function){
        // It doesn't work.
    }

    Entry(const std::function<F> function) :
        internalFunction(function) {

    }

    template<class... Arguments>
    auto operator()(Arguments... arguments) -> decltype(internalFunction(arguments...)){
        return internalFunction(arguments...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. But how can I implement constructor that will take function pointer or lambda as an argument? For example: Entry entry([]() {return 0;});

Comment: @Nuurek: With a lambda it gets much, much more complicated. You might be better off writing a specialization only for functor-like objects (like a lambda).

Comment: My last question: passing function as a parameter? Something like: 
void function() {}
Entry entry(function);
?

Comment: @Nuurek: If you notice, `std::function` requires that you specify return type and arguments. It does this specifically so it can use type-erasure to generically store anything that is basically the same thing as a function with that return type and argument list. If you only want to take a single parameter, things will get very difficult for you. I'm not entirely convinced it's possible, but if it is then the amount of meta-programming to accomplish it would be enormous.